# Having trouble extracting html data with xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping

Currently I'm trying to extract the location data from specific IPs in talosintelligence. When I run this code, it returns nothing.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. In this case, I would prefer for it to return "Charlotte, United States". Instead I just get an empty list.

What am I doing wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#pip install lxml
#pip install requests

from lxml import html 
import requests

page = requests.get('https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=198.86.225.18')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

#gets talos ip location 
talosiploc = tree.xpath('//*[@id="location-data-wrapper"]/table/tr/td/text()')
print(talosiploc)
```

Comment: Your xpath seems to be ok. Please make sure `page.content` has what you're looking for by `print` or `pprint`. I'd suggest using `BeautifulSoup`. You can also use `regex` on `page.content` and get the required data.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request and got **403** response code **forbidden**.
This web use anti-bot security **CloudFlare**.   How to **bypass** CloudFlare bot **protection**?
It depends.... Sometimes it is very difficult task or impossible.
That you need to do, is simulate a **real user** with the **browser**.
Try to use [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro), with pw you have 3 browsers: chromium, firefox and webkit.
Here you have some example of working code:

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.webkit.launch(headless=True)
    baseurl = "https://talosintelligence.com/reputation_center/lookup?search=198.86.225.18"
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto(baseurl)
    title = page.wait_for_selector('//*[@id="location-data-wrapper"]/table/tr/td')
    print("Country: " + title.text_content())
    browser.close()
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Country: Charlotte, United States
```

I hope I have been able to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that tonight. I was beginning to wonder if the site itself did not allow it...how do you know when you get the 403 error? I was running mine in pycharm.

Comment: I use IDE PyCharm and when you put break point on the next line after page. You inspect page value (after request), you will see **<Response [403]>**.